# Взять переменную из localStorage и добавить в url как параметр при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, url, localstorage

Например в localStorage есть записанные данные:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Каким способом возможно реализовать передачу этих данных в URL во время загрузки страницы. Что бы в результате:

```
mysite.com/page1/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Идеально реализовать через Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
var qs = '';
for (var i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  var key = localStorage.key(i);
  if (i !== 0) { qs += '&'; }
  qs += key + '=' + localStorage.getItem(key);
}
var newPath = window.location.path.substring(0, s.indexOf('?'));
if (newPath !== window.location.path) {
  window.location.replace(newPath);
}
```

Перехватить запрос и сразу отправить его с GET-параметрами не получится, в любом случае будет два запроса: без параметров и с ними, потому как исполнение скрипта начнется после загрузки страницы.